# In Asp.Net, check for existence of aspx page before redirecting to it?

Tags: asp.net, redirect

How can I check for the existence of an aspx page before attempting to redirect to it, so I can handle that case in my C# code?

```
Response.Redict("~/SomePage.aspx")
```

But I want to make sure that page really does exist before I call it. It works off of a string after all, so maybe I have a type or something, or maybe I have not created that page yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do a [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28VS.71%29.aspx) on the page.

```
  if(File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/SomePage.aspx")))
    Response.Redirect("~/SomePage.aspx");
```

You'll need to use the System.IO namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the extra hint about the namespace.

Comment: I got this additional info from another source. Just FYI to other users:

MapPath() only works within the virtual directory structure. ie. you can't navigate above the virtual directory with it and that's actually by design for security issues.

Answer (score 3):

```
File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/SomePage.aspx"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is on the same server then You can [check if the file exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) and then redirect the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.FileExists("~/SomePage.aspx");
```